# How can I access function caller in strict mode at JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, logging, strict

I'm using

- React
- tanstackQuery
- axios

I read that function `caller` is deprecated since ES5(not sure ES5). So I can't use it in strict mode. I don't think disabling strict mode is good idea. **Is there any good alternative functions or properties which can be used in `strict mode`?**

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_caller_or_arguments_usage) is a link that i read. There is no alternate in here.

Here is an error message when i try to use caller.

`TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them`

###### By the way, this is the first question on stack overflow. I don't know about question rules. I'm glad to if you let me know.

Thank you.

I try to see logs in strict mode.
I'd like to see where did it called from.
So i access function caller.
But i saw an error message.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help Here's the help center containing all the rules for question asking.

Comment: ["_the API is removed with no replacement_"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller).

Comment: If you're debugging, why not use the `debugger`? You could also use `console.error` which will give you a call stack.

Comment: You cannot, and you should not. If it's just about logging, use `console.trace` or error stack traces.

Answer (score 0):

Seems not possible. But you can get a caller's name and if the caller is accessible from the callee's scope you can eval the caller. Not sure if that's ok to use in production.

Anyway if you need a caller, pass it as an argument to a callee.
If you need a caller for a logic (not debugging) that could be a symptom of using a bad design pattern.

```js
'use strict';
{
  function fnCaller(){
    fnCallee();
  }

  function fnCallee(){

    console.log(eval(callerName()));

  }

  fnCaller();
}
```

```html
<script>

function callerName(){
  try{
    throw new Error;
  }catch(e){
    return e.stack.split('\n')[3].match(/(?<=^\s*at\s*)\S+/)[0];
  }
}

</script>
```